# layout - call left column block within main column (in the 1column.phtml template)

Tags: category, template, layout

I have a category list page which uses the 1column.phtml template. However, when the user navigates to a category where there are no subcategories - and only its products are displayed - I would like to call the left column.
The problem is that it is that I am still using the 1column template for this situation.

How can I call the left column?

Comment: If you want a left column - then it isn't a `1column` layout any more, its a `2col-left` layout. Why not just change the root template of your categories that need this layout? You could do some block manipulation fairly easily with XML - but it goes a bit against the point of having a `2col-left` layout if you are putting a left col in your `1column` layout.

Comment: I use 1column for my category lists because in most instances (when categories have subcategories) I do not want a left column. However, in one instance (when there are no subcategories) I want the left column.

Comment: Then you could rewrite the category controller - and set the layout handle and root template for the category conditionally - based on whether it had products or not. That would work.

Comment: ok. how would I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I remember correctly, the [`CategoryController` adds a layout handle for categories with no subcategories [link]](https://github.com/benmarks/magento-mirror/blob/1.7.0.2/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/controllers/CategoryController.php#L129), meaning that this can be done via layout XML, e.g. in *local.xml* layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layout>
    <catalog_category_layered_nochildren>
        <action method="setTemplate" block="root">
            <tpl>page/2columns-left.phtml</tpl>
        </action>
    </catalog_category_layered_nochildren>
</layout>
```

Comment: <catalog_category_layered_nochildren translate="label">
     <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-left.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>
    </catalog_category_layered_nochildren>   This is the code I wrote but I am still getting 1column.phtml... why do you think this is happening?

Comment: never mind - "isAnchor" issues were the problem... thank you very much!

Comment: super benmarks :( all of my work was for nothing :) I like short answers! Thanks benmarks. TIL: there is `catalog_category_layered_nochildren`.

Comment: @FabianBlechschmidt - please do not think that your work was for nothing - it taught me how to make observers - and while I did not need it in this instance, I will surely need it elsewhere...

Comment: Oh no, I don't think that :-) And I'm eager to learn more. So everything is alright.

Answer (score 2):

## For a single category:

You can change the layout for the single category. To do this, go to the categorie in the backend, open the tab `Custom Layout` and choose "2 columns with left bar" in `Page Layout` dropdown.

## Implementing an observer

I think listening on `core_block_abstract_to_html_before` might be a good idea. Check wether the block is `root`. If it is a category, the category can be found in `Mage::registry('current_category');`. Then you check for `hasChildren()` and if it has, set the Template for the root block.

I'm not sure whether this is enough. Maybe you need to change the update handle too.

### Implementation

Observer.php

```
public function coreBlockAbstractToHtmlBefore(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    /* @var $block Mage_Core_Block_Template */
    $block = $observer->getBlock();
    if($block->getNameInLayout() == 'root') {
        /* lvar $category Mage_Catalog_Model_Category */
        if(($category = Mage::registry('current_category')) && $category instanceof Mage_Catalog_Model_Category) {
            if(!$category->hasChildren()) {
                $block->setTemplate('page/2columns-left.phtml');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

config.xml

```
<config>
    <frontend>
        <events>
            <core_block_abstract_to_html_before>
                <observers>
                    <namespace_mymodule>
                        <type>model</type>
                        <class>Namespace_MyModule_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>coreBlockAbstractToHtmlBefore</method>
                    </namespace_mymodule>
                </observers>
            </core_block_abstract_to_html_before>
        </events>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

Comment: thank you - but this would be too time consuming to do for every single category...

Comment: ah, I misinterpreted your "in one instance" :) Then you can implement a observer :) I'll edit my answer

Comment: @FabianBlechschmidt That's exactly what I was getting at. A nice clean & simple solution.

Comment: Is it possible to add some more explanation (I am still new at anything in Magento's "code" folder...)

Comment: Personally, I would prefer @FabianBlechschmidt 's first method, simply updating the layout in each category's custom layout section. The reason being is that it is more obvious why the layout is changing on a specific category, rather than being set in an observer which will confuse someone down the road. If you're concerned with having to do this for many categories (how many are we talking?) then a simple script executed once could programmatically set these for you.

Comment: I cannot do this for every category. Do you know how I would go about implemeting @FabianBlechschmidt's second method?

Comment: added implementation.

Comment: @FabianBlechschmidt thank you for all the detail!