# How can I change the layout of my category (product) page from 2column to 1column using local.xml

Tags: magento-1.9, category, layout

Setting:

- Using Magento 1.9
- My Default template is `2column_left` set at my `local.xml` (as shown below)

My categories are as follows and `isAnchor=No`:

```
Top1
  Sub1-Top1
    Sub1-Sub1-Top1
  Sub2-Top1 
  Sub3-Top1
    Sub1-Sub3-Top1
Top2
   Sub1-Top2 
   Sub2-Top2
     Sub1-Sub2-Top2
```

Scenario:

I would like the layout for **Sub2-Top1** and **Sub1-Top2** (no subcategories) to have the `1column` template and the rest should have the `2column_left`. But I cannot seem to get it correctly.

I was trying to accomplish this task from the examples:

- [layout - call left column block within main column (in the 1column.phtml template)](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/1010/layout-call-left-column-block-within-main-column-in-the-1column-phtml-templat)
- and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9763350/how-to-change-the-page-layout-in-magento

`local.xml`

```
  <ep_catalog_category_template>
    <reference name="root">
      <action method="setTemplate">
        <template>page/2columns-left.phtml</template>
      </action>
    </reference>
  </ep_catalog_category_template>

  <ep_no_catalog_category_template>
    <reference name="category.products">
      <action method="setTemplate">
        <template>page/1column.phtml</template>
      </action>
    </reference>
  </ep_no_catalog_category_template>

  <catalog_category_layered>
    <update handle="ep_catalog_category_template" />
  </catalog_category_layered>

  <catalog_category_default>
    <update handle="ep_catalog_category_template" />
  </catalog_category_default>

  <catalog_category_layered_nochildren>
    <reference name="category.products">
      <action method="setTemplate">
        <template>page/1column.phtml</template>
      </action>
    </reference>
  </catalog_category_layered_nochildren>
```

The `catalog_category_layered_nochildren` tag should replace the default template to `1column` but it is not working. Instead the output page is `2column` with the left side contains no content and the main content has the list of products. I would like the list of products to use all the page -- thus removing the `left_column` ergo `1column`. Can it be done using `local.xml`? or better yet, how can I do this?

Comment: It is possible to do this in the admin, if one does not have many categories. `Under Catalog -> Manage -> Categories ->Custom Design Tab -> Page Layout` change the layout to 1column. But still looking for a way to do it using local.xml.

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19229441/magento-find-a-layout-handle-for-product-category-page

Comment: Thanks for that R.S., It was the last piece of the puzzle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Still a noob. There is still a lot to learn. The real answer is understanding the whole concept.

1. Didn't realize the `IsAnchor` Option for the categories. `IsAnchor` provides the filters on the left column, and this I need for all the category page which has subcategories.
2. `IsAnchor=Yes` uses the `catalog_category_layered` whereas `IsAnchor=No` uses the `catalog_category_default` XML settings respectively.
3. Didn't know exactly when and where does the `catalog_category_layered_nochildren` comes in the process and how it should be implemented.

I finally came to a solution after working backwards.

1. Since I know that I will use the `catalog_category_layered_nochildren` handle (and I wasn't able to find something like `catalog_category_default_nochildren`), I set all my categories to `IsAnchor=Yes`.
2. From that, I will not need the extra code for `catalog_category_default`.
3. The sequence of the layout handles as pointed out by R.S., https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19229441/magento-find-a-layout-handle-for-product-category-page
   made it impossible for me to make the 
   `catalog_category_layered_nochildren` execute correctly since the `catalog_category_layered` will overwrite it so I keep getting the `2column_left` instead of `1column` for the categories without subcategories. Realizing the `default` handle, I set my `2column_left` there.
   My final `local.xml`

   ```
   <default>
     <reference name="root">
       <action method="setTemplate">
         <template>page/2columns-left.phtml</template>
       </action>
     </reference>
   </default>

   <catalog_category_layered_nochildren>
     <reference name="root">
       <action method="setTemplate">
         <template>page/1column.phtml</template>
       </action>
     </reference>
   </catalog_category_layered_nochildren>
   ```

Now all the categories without subcategories will have `1column` layout, and all the rest will have `2column_left`.

CB